# Push Notifications iOS and Android Client-to-Client Native Code

Tags: android, ios, notifications, push-notification, push

so I am planning an App for both iOS and Android. Both Apps will use Native Code, so Objective-C on iOS 6 and Java with Android SDK 4.0 (API 14).

The App will connect to a shared MySQL Database (C / JDBC).

It should be able to send and receive Push Notifications from both Platforms in both directions. The Notifications won't contain any payload data, they will only be used to inform that there's new Data in the Database, coupled with a String which describes the Type of new Data (like "There's an update to Event X available"). On reception the Receiver should update its Data according to the new entries in the Database.

I am searching for a non-paid service / server software / Build-In functionality which use the Google GCM and Apple APNS Push Services to implement the functionality.

While researching I already found some possible solutions (PushWoosh, pushd, PushSharp, PubNub, OpenPush) but none of them match my requirements (based on mono, paid, using sockets...).

Do you know of such a solution? I am open to other suggestions too.

Regards,
Mike

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning i want to point that i haven't developed any Android app with push notifications. But for my iOS applications, i declare a php function in server API, and when ever a change happens tos related users in MySQL database, i call that function and it ***triggers*** APNS. It uses server certificates given from Apple and user credentials to interact with just related user(like SMS system).. I think that function can be customized in order to use Google's certificates too(if there is any, i dont know how Google handles Push notifications)..

Answer (score 1):

This is very possible.  its a deep topic though, too deep for one stack post.

Here is a tutorial for [iOS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12) and here is the google docs for [android GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html)

These are definitely the tools you would want to use!